# JavaScript search bar - needs to search <li> and <dd>

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to alter my current javascript so it provides the results whether they are in the question or answer.

Currently, the search will provide the results based on the button text. I'd like to include the button text AND the answer text. I have also provided the script for the show/hide when clicked.

```js
function mySearch() {

  var input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
    li = document.querySelectorAll(".ul li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var a = li[i].querySelector("button");

    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var answer = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (answer.style.display === "block") {
      answer.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      answer.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="What do you need help with?" title="search">

<ul id="myUL1" class="ul">
  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">What does on-demand learning mean?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">On-demand learning is a...
    </dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">How do I get credit for the courses I take? Does The University keep track, or do I have to?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Credit, check! Tracking, check!
    </dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">Can I visit every academy?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Go for it! You can visit each academy and explore their resources.</dd>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">If I have technical problems, what do I do?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">If you have technical problems, submit a case to.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">Can I attend classes/workshops or take advantage of the on-demand
                content while I am not at work?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Time spent attending classes/workshops and/or ... timesheet.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">How do I find available workshops?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Check out the Workshops .. latest workshop offerings.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">Is there a way to request a workshop that is not currently being
                offered?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Yes, you can request a workshop that is not currently being offered by searching for the workshop, selecting the workshop and selecting the Notify Me option.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">What is the differenc...</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;"> but the underlying functionalities will remain the same because it is still in Cornerstone.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">I am on the waitlist; how will I know if I have been added to the
                roster?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">If you are moved to a workshop roster from the waitlist, you will receive an email with workshop details.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">How do I know who to go to with content questions?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">For L&D Academy content questions, submit a case to .</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">If something is incorrect on my transcript, who do I need to
                contact to get it resolved?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">To update information on your transcript, </dd>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69901301/295783)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same thing you've done with the button text :

```js
function mySearch() {

  var input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
    li = document.querySelectorAll(".ul li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var a = li[i].querySelector("button");
    var d = li[i].querySelector(".answer"); //get the element containing the answer

    //check wether the filter matches the question or the answer
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || d.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}


var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("question");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var answer = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (answer.style.display === "block") {
      answer.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      answer.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="What do you need help with?" title="search">

<ul id="myUL1" class="ul">
  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">What does on-demand learning mean?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">On-demand learning is a...
    </dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">How do I get credit for the courses I take? Does The University keep track, or do I have to?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Credit, check! Tracking, check!
    </dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">Can I visit every academy?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Go for it! You can visit each academy and explore their resources.</dd>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">If I have technical problems, what do I do?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">If you have technical problems, submit a case to.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">Can I attend classes/workshops or take advantage of the on-demand
                content while I am not at work?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Time spent attending classes/workshops and/or ... timesheet.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">How do I find available workshops?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Check out the Workshops .. latest workshop offerings.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">Is there a way to request a workshop that is not currently being
                offered?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">Yes, you can request a workshop that is not currently being offered by searching for the workshop, selecting the workshop and selecting the Notify Me option.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">What is the differenc...</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;"> but the underlying functionalities will remain the same because it is still in Cornerstone.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">I am on the waitlist; how will I know if I have been added to the
                roster?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">If you are moved to a workshop roster from the waitlist, you will receive an email with workshop details.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">How do I know who to go to with content questions?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">For L&D Academy content questions, submit a case to .</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" onclick="myShow()">If something is incorrect on my transcript, who do I need to
                contact to get it resolved?</button>
    <dd class="answer" style="display: none;">To update information on your transcript, </dd>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

this is the simplest

```
const input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
  lis = document.querySelectorAll(".ul li");

// Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
lis.forEach(li => {
  const found =  li.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
  li.hidden = filter && !found
})
```

I also had a look at the reveal code - I removed all inline clicks and display:none - To delegate is more elegant

```
myUL1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("question")) {
    tgt.classList.toggle("active");
    const answer = tgt.nextElementSibling; 
    answer.hidden = !answer.hidden;
  }
});
```

```js
function mySearch() {

  const input = document.getElementById('myInput'),
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
    lis = document.querySelectorAll(".ul li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  lis.forEach(li => {
    const found = li.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1
    li.hidden = filter && !found
  })
}



myUL1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("question")) {
    tgt.classList.toggle("active");
    const answer = tgt.nextElementSibling; 
    answer.hidden = !answer.hidden;
  }
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: white; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="What do you need help with?" title="search">

<ul id="myUL1" class="ul">
  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >What does on-demand learning mean?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>On-demand learning is a...
    </dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >How do I get credit for the courses I take? Does The University keep track, or do I have to?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>Credit, check! Tracking, check!
    </dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >Can I visit every academy?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>Go for it! You can visit each academy and explore their resources.</dd>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >If I have technical problems, what do I do?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>If you have technical problems, submit a case to.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >Can I attend classes/workshops or take advantage of the on-demand
                content while I am not at work?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>Time spent attending classes/workshops and/or ... timesheet.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >How do I find available workshops?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>Check out the Workshops .. latest workshop offerings.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >Is there a way to request a workshop that is not currently being
                offered?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>Yes, you can request a workshop that is not currently being offered by searching for the workshop, selecting the workshop and selecting the Notify Me option.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >What is the differenc...</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden> but the underlying functionalities will remain the same because it is still in Cornerstone.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >I am on the waitlist; how will I know if I have been added to the
                roster?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>If you are moved to a workshop roster from the waitlist, you will receive an email with workshop details.</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >How do I know who to go to with content questions?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>For L&D Academy content questions, submit a case to .</dd>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button class="question" type="button" >If something is incorrect on my transcript, who do I need to
                contact to get it resolved?</button>
    <dd class="answer" hidden>To update information on your transcript, </dd>
  </li>
</ul>
```